# Best approach for an Ajax system?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, service, web

Hi I wonder if anyone can help me. I want to create an Ajax system that allows to display and search records. At the moment I pass a function name and values to a file called userUpdate.aspx the brings back data. My problem is I want to add extra features such as autocomplete. I have looked at examples and they all use web methods and services. should I move my Ajax calls to web methods instead of an aspx file and what advantages will this bring?

Comment: Thanks for the advice. You have been much help. Will try using web services for my ajax calls.

Answer (score 1):

> Should I move my Ajax calls to web methods instead of an aspx file and
>   what advantages will this bring?

Certainly moving some methods to a Web Service or exposing them as Page Methods will allow you to make Ajax requests easily with jQuery, for example. If you go the MS Ajax route, you'll have to use Update Panels and Script Managers which are inefficient and will never perform as good as a regular Ajax request that does not trigger the full page life-cycle. As a result, your requests are lighter, faster and slimmer (they carry less data).

Comment: Personally, I prefer the jquery route.  That being said, I think MS ajax route isn't bad (minus update panels).  Using the javascript proxy from adding a script reference to a script manager is actually somewhat convenient.